# Is there a existing library for search function (e. g. include/exclude, and/or)?

Tags: java, search, text

I have a JavaFX application with a TableView. The user can filter the displayed rows with a search term they enter in a TextField.

Currently I iterate over all cells and use simply `String.contains()`.
I want to enhance it, so the user can also enter e. g.:

```
"hello OR hallo -world columnB:abc".  
-> include or exclude ("-world"), 
AND or OR combinations, search in particular columns ("columnB:abc") and so on.
```

Is there an existing library which I can use?

I searched on the web, but didn't find a library for this use case.
Search engines like Apache Lucene, Apache Solr, Elasticsearch seem not to fit (overload for this simple use case and I have already structured data (TableView) - no full text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *ANTLR*

Found a promising solution: a parser generator like [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/). (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR).)

Using a grammar file as input it allows you to generate a parser. With it you get a parse tree at runtime which you can then process in your application.

Comment: You could improve your answer by summarising its features.  Link only answers may get removed by the bot.